# zf2 what is meant by dispatch, dispatcher?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to zend framework
I feel confusing with the term dispatch and the dispather, dispatchable

Can someone illustrate ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the implementation differs, these terms are not new to ZF2; they are language-agnostic and generally refer to the MVC design pattern.

**Dispatch**

The [name of event](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events). This is the event that signifies the execution of the target  controller's method (that was matched in routing).

> `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` Dispatch the matched route to a controller/action.

**Dispatchable**

A controller class (implementing `Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface`) that *listens* to the dispatch event.

**Dispatcher** (noun)

Something responsible for 'triggering' or 'doing' the dispatch. (This was actually an interface/class in ZF1 however now it is achieved using the event manager)